# LWC download ContentDocument with alternative name

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, contentdocument, content

I have a LWC component where i render some `ContentDocument` information.

If the user goes to `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId`  (e.g. by clicking on a `anchor tag (<a href='...')` then they get the file downloaded.

However, the filename is the actual ContentDocument Name.

Due to some business logic, i want the filename to be much longer and contain info from some linked records, e.g. i want the file name on the user's computer to actually say 'Extra Stuff - {ContentDocument.Title}` or something.

I tried using `download.js` (http://danml.com/download.html#Download) as well as `fetch()` api.

Download.js actually works, except it crashes Aura somewhere (and i suspect might not pass the Security Review); and `fetch` simply dies complaining about CORS or other CSP.

All i want is for the ability to specify the filename.